# How to find out if the phone rings

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart

I have a flutter music player. I want to notice when the phone is ringing to pause the audio player. How do I do this?

Comment: most likely it should be implemented in the player you are using, what package is it?

Comment: Audio players package ( https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers )

Comment: no, that package does not provide such an option - you have to do that by yourself using the packages like in the below answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use these two packages for detecting the phone call state. Choose any one of'em and proceed.

1. [phone_state_i](https://pub.dev/packages/phone_state_i)
2. [phonecallstate](https://pub.dev/packages/phonecallstate)

Any of them will help you. In flutter try to find packages, not do the full code. They have bunch of packages, hence make it more reliable platform for development.

Comment: also is it possible to have anything like this for phone alarm?